# Web sockets como fazer uma conexão selecionando um IP

Tags: javascript, html, arduino, websocket

Estou fazendo um projeto que envolve conexão com um *ESP8266* através de `websockets`, porém como o *ip* do `ESP` não e estático necessita fazer a conexão manual com o *IP*. Porem no código abaixo quando coloco os métodos de conexão dentro de uma função, os outros métodos do `websocket` não são reconhecidos como válidos

> (`ONOPEN ONMESSAGE e ONERROR`)

Quero saber se existe uma maneira de escolher o *ip* e fazer a conexão.

```
var connection;
function Conectar(){
        var text = document.getElementById('ip').value;
        ipValue = "ws://"+text+":81/";
        connection = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.41:81/', ['arduino']);
        LerEstado();
};

connection.onopen = function () {
    console.log("CONECTADO");
    LerEstado();
};

connection.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log('WebSocket Error '+ error);
};

connection.onmessage = function (e) {
    LerEstado();
    var mensagem = e.data;
    console.log('Recebido ESP8266: '+ mensagem);
    var letra = mensagem.charAt(0);
};
```